# Monotouch Crash: Replace UINavigationController A with B and Push UiViewControllers on B

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, uistoryboard

We have been using Xamarin for a while and it is causing a weird crash while developing the latest iPad app. Following is the problem:

The ipad App uses a story board with 2 Navigation controllers (say A and B) each has a RootViewCOntroller (say A1 and B1), with A as default NavController and is showed on APP start up. There is 2 buttons on A1 , pressing button 1  loads NavController B.Here are the steps that code execute when the button one on NavController A is clicked.

In the Button Event handler , I call a public function in AppDelegate which does the following:

- Get the StoryBoard iD and instantiate the NavController B using storyboard.InstantiateViewCOntroller.
- Remove the NavCOntroller A from its superview (using UIView.View.RemoveSuperView())
- Assign the above reference of B to the appdelegate window's Root view controller (which loads the rootview controller B1 of NavCOntroller B).

It works fine till the above step (I can see the rootviewcontroller's UiView load on iPad).

the next step I am trying to push another UiViewController after Instantiating it.(Because my target is 2 show the second screen in hierarchy) (storyboard.InstantiateViewController(identifier).This should ideally show me the pushed view controller.But the app crashes after this step.!! WEIRD!!!!.
Following is the simplified code:

```
public void SetNavControllerB(UINavigationController navA, UiStoryBoard StoryBoard)
{
   navA.View.RemoveFromSuperView();

   this.Window.RootViewController = (UiNavigationController)StoryBoard.InstantiateViewController("VC0");
   // 'VC0' is the identifier for NavigationController B with RootViewController as "VC1"

  // It works great till the above step

   UiViewController vc2 = (UiViewController)StoryBoard.InstantiateViewController("VC2");
   ((UINavigationController)this.Window.RootViewController).PushViewController(vc2, true);

   //The above executes with out any exception, but it crashes later.
}
```

Pleaseeeee help!!!!!!

Comment: Jonathan, Thanks a million for your response.  Your answer helped me to move a bit further. I modified to the following:

UINavigationController uiNav = storyBoard.InstantiateViewController("vc0");

uiNav.SetViewControllers(new UiViewController[] {uiNav.ViewController[0], storyBoard.InstantiateviewController("vc2")}, true);

And amazingly the APP showed up the second VC of Navcontroller B with out any crash. However it raised another problem:

Comment: Continuing the above comment:

when back button on VC2 is pressed, the app crashes. 

I have implemented a custom swipe right segue (which performs the same function as 'back' button (pops the viewcontroller)). When i swipe right, it crashes there too.

Did you find anything fishy? Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

If you are modifying the stack in a `UINavigationController` beyond a push or pop, then you need to replace its entire stack of controllers:

```
myNavController.SetViewControllers(new UIViewController[] { controller1, controller2 }, true);
```

If you try to push or pop before a previous push or pop completes, then you will get a  crash and a warning in the console output.

PS - I don't think you should need to call `RemoveFromSuperview` anywhere in your situation, you should just modify the `UINavigationController's` stack or replace `RootViewController` on your window.

Comment: Jonathan, Thanks a million for your response.  Your answer helped me to move a bit further. I modified to the following:

UINavigationController uiNav = storyBoard.InstantiateViewController("vc0");

uiNav.SetViewControllers(new UiViewController[] {uiNav.ViewController[0], storyBoard.InstantiateviewController("vc2")}, true);

And amazingly the APP showed up the second VC of Navcontroller B with out any crash. However it raised another problem:

Comment: Continuing the above comment:

when back button on VC2 is pressed, the app crashes. 

I have implemented a custom swipe right segue (which performs the same function as 'back' button (pops the viewcontroller)). When i swipe right, it crashes there too.

Did you find anything fishy? Thank you again.

Comment: Jonathan: i also found that, after i set the viewcontrollers on NavStack using myNavController.SetViewControllers(..., true), which makes the last viewcontroller show on app (as expected); but thew viewdidload() method of the viewcontrollers under the top controller were not being called.

Comment: Continuing...Probably thats the reason my app crashes when i press 'back' button on VC.

Comment: Can you provide the exception stacktrace, and anything you see in the console output?